# Delete element from array when deleting record from localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a localStorage object like this:

Key: `jpxun`

Value: `[{"id":"0","name":"royal"},{"id":"1","name":"tippins"},{"id":"4","name":"leviosa"},{"id":"5","name":"vicious"}]`

I have this JS to display output the localStorage:

```
var jpxun = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jpxun')) || [];

if (jpxun) {
    var jpxun_length = jpxun.length;
} else {
    var jpxun_length = 0;
}

var hst = document.getElementById("usernames");

var MyUsernames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jpxun"));

if (jpxun_length > 0) {

    // declare array to hold items for outputting later in plain text format
    var plain_text_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < MyUsernames.length; i++) {

        var un1 = MyUsernames[i].name;

        hst.innerHTML += "<li>" +"<a id="+MyUsernames[i].id + " href='#content' onclick='deleteById(this)'>x </a>" + un1 + "</li>";

        // add word to plain text array
        plain_text_array.push(un1);

    }

}
```

Each element is outputted in a list item with an 'x' as a hyperlink so that it can be clicked and that element is deleted from localStorage.

This is the code to delete the item from localStorage:

```
var deleteById = function ( self ){

  MyUsernames = MyUsernames.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.id !== self.id;
  });
          
  localStorage.setItem("jpxun",JSON.stringify(MyUsernames));
  
  self.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(self.parentNode);
  
}
```

That works fine.

Unfortunately I don't really understand how the code works in `deleteById`.

As that is the case, I am stuck on working out how to delete the corresponding record from `plain_text_array` when its value is deleted from localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to find the text in the array thats includes that string `'id="item_id"'`:

```
plain_text_array = plain_text_array.filter(item => !item.includes(`id="${self.id}"`));
```

Just add it in the end of `deleteById` function.

Comment: Hi @Asaf - thanks for your reply. Does the `$` in your code imply the code is jQuery code? The rest of my code isn't jQuery, which makes it tricky to plug it into the existing code. Sorry though if I'm wrong there. Thanks.

Comment: Hi it's in javascript ES6

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: It's more straightforward than the alternative: `'id="'+self.id+'"'`